# MongoDB: "can't save partial objects" exception

Tags: java, mongodb, insert, database

I'm trying to query from one collection and insert into another using the Java API, but I'm getting an exception I don't understand:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't save partial objects
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection._checkObject(DBCollection.java:1380)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:222)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:205)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:57)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:100)
```

Is there some "finalize" method I need to call on the document or something?  My code goes like this:

```
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;

Mongo mongo = new Mongo("mongodb://...");
DB db = mongo.getDB("foo");
DBCollection rawCollection = db.getCollection("foo1");
DBCollection aggCollection = db.getCollection("foo2");

DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours(-5);

BasicDBObject toGrab = new BasicDBObject("Time1", 1).append("col2", 1).append("col3", 1);
DBCursor c = rawCollection.find(null, toGrab).limit(10);

for (DBObject doc : c) {
  Date newDate = new DateTime( ((BasicBSONObject) doc).getDate("Time1") )
                   .withZone(tz).monthOfYear().roundCeilingCopy()
                   .withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).toDate();

  doc.put("Time2", newDate);

  aggCollection.insert(doc);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are querying for specific fields using collection.find(query,**projection**)

By specifying **projection** in the arguments to a find operation, the collection is returning you a partial object.

From the posted stack trace, when calling 'insert', the underlying API is running _checkObject(doc), which throws the exception for a "partial object", as this is the same instance returned by cursor.

You could get around this by creating (new BasicDBObject(doc)) effectively copying the returned partial object, and then saving the copy to the aggCollection..

```
BasicDBObject doc = ...;
BasicDBObject copyOfDoc = new BasicDBObject(doc);
copyOfDoc.put("Time2", newDate);
aggCollection.insert(copyOfDoc);
```

See [Find](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find) and the [collection source](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jackrabbit/oak/tags/jackrabbit-oak-0.5/oak-mongomk/src/test/java/com/mongodb/DBCollection.java) and the [map constructor](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html#BasicDBObject%28java.util.Map%29).

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any such method `new BasicDBObject(doc)`, is there some other easy way to clone a document?  Or do I have to go field by field?

Comment: The constructor for BasicDBObject takes a Map, creating an object with all of the properties in the map. BasicDBObject also implements the Map interface, so you can create a new BasicDBObject with all of the same properties as basicDBObject1 by using the source object as an instance of Map (Ain't polymorphism grand?). I'll edit the answer with a code example.

Comment: What tripped me up is that `BasicDBObject` implements `Map`, but queries return `DBObject`s, which doesn't implement `Map`.  So I just need to cast.  Not the prettiest interface, but it should work, thanks.